# Is it possible to add a Push/Refresh view to Browser#1 when order is placed on Browser#2 in Django?

Tags: django

I'm creating a kitchen app/order app.  And I'm trying to make the kitchen browser page refresh when an order is placed from another browser.

Is this even possible?

I know Django can use Signals to track events, but can those events trigger a refresh on another browser?

Comment: The answer to almost all "Is it possible" question is "yes".

Comment: Rather than asking "is it possible to do X with Y?" I recommend that you google "how do I do X". You most likely cannot do this purely with python. You will need to write some javascript that handles this in the browser.